# AP1509-50SG Passive Component Values

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

I have a circuit of which I'm using a 5V LDO Regulator and I'm looking at converting it to use a switching regulator.

On the datasheet for the 5V Fixed version of the AP1509 a value for the inductor is given but for the 3.3V Version. But isn't for the 5V Version.

I did find the application note at https://static5.arrow.com/pdfs/2012/11/23/1/33/0/620/dds_/manual/anp013_1509.pdf but when trying to calculate the inductance I get an inductance value of 74uH but am not sure if this is correct.

Also is there any recommended Capacitor value for the input and input? On the linear regulator I have a 100nF ceramic on the input and a 33uF Tantalum on the output (as well as a few 100nF near the components using the power). Would the same be acceptable on a switching?

Comment: Capacitor values should be in the datasheet. If not, bin it.

Comment: Not a helpful comment at all @LeonHeller

Answer (score 0):

74uH seems a little too high, but it's not unexpected for inductance values for buck converters. I'd just roll with it.

About the capacitors, usually adding more capacitance only hurts the transient response of the buck converter and not harm the stability a lot. Leon Heller is right in that if the manufacturer doesn't specify the recommended capacitance it's kind of trash.

I recommend setting the resonant frequency of the LC filter of the buck converter to something like 10% of the switching frequency or even lower than that (i.e. higher capacitance than that). Should give you a good margin and low switching noise.